# Javascript button for two functions. Submit & OnClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are trying to link our form's submit button to work as a submit button and function the following Javascript.

Button:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="button button--red">Sign Up</button>
```

It works when we remove the id="btn_submit"  to submit, but when we add the id="btn_submit"  it implements the Javascript.  How could we have the one button achieve both functions?

Javascript (beginning):

```
$("#btn_submit").on('click', function() {
```

Many, Many thanks!

Comment: `$("#btn_submit").on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); //do code $('form#myForm').submit();` try this way

Comment: @guradio  Thanks soooooo much!! That's exactly what we needed!!

Comment: glad it works @Lanie909 mind if i put it as answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#btn_submit").on('click', function(e) { 
e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting
//do your code here
$('form#myForm').submit(); //submit your form here
```

One way to do this is dont submit your form on button click after doing all the other code you can submit your form manually

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn_submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //do stuff

    $("#form").submit();
}
```

Where "#form" represents the id of your form. So if your form is "my_form", then change the above to read $("#my_form").submit();